# NGINX: Connect to backend with service name over Docker Compose's network from frontend

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, axios

I have a [simple dockerized flask backend](https://github.com/tobiaslocker/simple-dockerized-flask-backend) that listens on `0.0.0.0:8080` and [simple dockerized react frontend](https://github.com/tobiaslocker/simple-dockerized-react-frontend) that sends a request to `localhost:8080/api/v1.0/resource`. 
Now i want to run those containers in docker compose and issue the request to the service's name `backend`
The compose file looks like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  backend:
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    image: "tobiaslocker/simple-dockerized-flask-backend:v0.1"
  frontend:
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    image: "tobiaslocker/simple-dockerized-react-frontend:v0.1"
```

The `NGINX` configuration that works for requests to `localhost`:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
  }
}
```

The frontend sends the request `axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/v1.0/resource')`

My questions:

1. How do i have to configure `NGINX` to be able to use the service name (e.g. `backend`)
2. How do i have to issue the request to match the configuration.

I am not sure how the `proxy_pass` will take effect when sending the request from the frontend and found it hard to debug.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Answers:

> 1. How do i have to configure NGINX to be able to use the service name (e.g. backend)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
    location /api {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://backend:8080;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

Taken from [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/configure-nginx-for-nodejs-backend-and-react-frontend-app). Not sure if all settings are relevant but only setting `proxy_pass` didn't work for me.

> 2. How do i have to issue the request to match the configuration.

Same as before: `axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/v1.0/resource')`, which makes sense, since it works locally and proxied with NGINX.